# Relationship between patient and address

Tags: mysql, rdbms

A patient if in a single family can have same address so there is probability of duplication , so is it necessary for the address to be a separate table .

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need to know* if multiple patients live at the same address? If not, it's simpler to treat it as a 1:1 relation and say that patients having identical addresses is unimportant.

Comment: would not that be against 3NF?

Comment: and can i use a separate table for mobile number ? since a patient can have multiple mobile number or is there a way to save multiple phone numbers in same field... thanks for helping

Comment: It would only be against 3NF if you need to keep track of addresses separate from the patients who use them. If you look at address as merely an attribute of the patient, it's completely normal.

Comment: As for phone numbers, you can normalize that out, or you can simply provide a fixed number of fields for (let's say) home, work & mobile numbers. In *practical* database design, there are occasions where a small amount of abnormality can save a great deal of headache. It all depends on what you need to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

An address can exist without a person. A person can exist without an address.

A person can live at more than one address (home, cottage).

Multiple people can live at the same address.

An address can be used for more than one purpose (home, work).

You can think of a phone number and postal address as concretions of an abstract address type.

Therefore, you want something like this:

```
create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  ...
);

create table addresses (
  address_id int primary key,
  type varchar(...) not null, -- POSTAL_ADDRESS or PHONE_NUMBER
  ...
);

create table people_addresses (
  person_id int references people(person_id),
  address_id int references addresses(address_id),
  role varchar(...), -- HOME, WORK, MOBILE
);
```